# Django Rest Framework - Extending token authentication class

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-authentication

I want to use the built in Token Authentication provided by the DRF. However, I only want Token Authentication to run if "mode=1" is not passed into the header. If that is passed into the header, then I want to use custom permission that does not involve user.

Is there any way I can extend the functionality of the already existing Token Authentication to do this or will I have to make a custom Token Authentication from scratch?

TLDR:

```
If request.META.get('HTTP_MODE', None) == '1':
    # Don't use token authentication, use custom permission class instead.
else:
    # Use built in token authentication
```

Comment: Yes, you can use a custom permission class. Don't use `if else`,  just add it to the list of authentication classes before token authentication. They will be tried in order. It's explained very well in the docs. http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#custom-authentication

Comment: I will have one authentication and one permission class, so I can't group them together. I want the token authentication to run and if it fails, return None (and go on to permissions). I think by default it throws error